# how can I install PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I Install PyTorch in Anaconda But when I write :

`pip install torchvision`

In anaconda this Error show me :

`No matching distribution found for torch==1.4.0 (from torchvision)`

Did I install it badly?

Comment: pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me. First install `MKL`:

```
conda install -c anaconda mkl
```

After this, install torchvision:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
```

For pip:

```
pip install pytorch torchvision
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the instructions on their [website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) worked fine. You can choose your configurations and get the command.

For conda use this (CPU Version):

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

Answer (score 0):

For pip environment (terminal) use this

```
pip3 install torchvision
```

For conda environment use this (run this command on anaconda prompt)

```
conda install PyTorch -c PyTorch
```